# MAUI Error APT2096 failed to open APK:Invalid file

Tags: maui, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0

Thanks for helping me.
I'm beginner to learn MAUI,I created a new MAUI project and without any change,just download associationed Android resources like 'Pixel 5 - API 33(Android 13.0 - API 33)'.

When I debug in Android Emulator,it occured an error

APT2096 failed to open APK:Invalid file

scrrenshot is this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puDKm.png)

and line 156 is

```
  <Aapt2Link
  Condition=" '$(_AndroidResourceDesignerFile)' != '' "
  ContinueOnError="$(DesignTimeBuild)"
  DaemonMaxInstanceCount="$(Aapt2DaemonMaxInstanceCount)"
  DaemonKeepInDomain="$(_Aapt2DaemonKeepInDomain)"
  AssemblyIdentityMapFile="$(_AndroidLibrayProjectAssemblyMapFile)"
  ImportsDirectory="$(_LibraryProjectImportsDirectoryName)"
  OutputImportDirectory="$(_AndroidLibrayProjectIntermediatePath)"
  OutputFile="$(ResgenTemporaryDirectory)\resources.apk"
  PackageName="$(_AndroidPackage)"
  JavaPlatformJarPath="$(JavaPlatformJarPath)"
  JavaDesignerOutputDirectory="$(ResgenTemporaryDirectory)"
  CompiledResourceFlatFiles="@(_CompiledFlatFiles)"
  ManifestFiles="$(ResgenTemporaryDirectory)\AndroidManifest.xml"
  AdditionalAndroidResourcePaths="@(_LibraryResourceDirectories)"
  YieldDuringToolExecution="$(YieldDuringToolExecution)"
  ResourceSymbolsTextFile="$(IntermediateOutputPath)R.txt"
  ResourceDirectories="$(MonoAndroidResDirIntermediate)"
  ExtraArgs="$(AndroidAapt2LinkExtraArgs)"
  ToolPath="$(Aapt2ToolPath)"
  ToolExe="$(Aapt2ToolExe)"
  UncompressedFileExtensions="$(AndroidStoreUncompressedFileExtensions)"
```

/>

Comment: Have you tried deploying other apps to your emulator? Will such a problem also arise?